# Firewalld %%REJECT%%

Tags: firewall, firewalld

I'm trying to configure `firewalld (v0.4.4.2)` on Debian 9 to `REJECT` invalid requests originating from an internal network.

However, if I set the default target of the zone in question to `REJECT`, the requests still appear to be dropped. (If I test it, I get connection times out instead of beeing rejected.)

According to the [docs](https://firewalld.org/documentation/zone/options.html), `REJECT` is not statically assigned, but:

> The %%REJECT%% target is used in block zone to reject (**with default
>   firewalld reject type**) every packet not matching any rule.

So it seems that default reject type is the wrong one.
I'm not sure how to change this. Thanks for any advice.

`iptables -L` (cropped):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
[...]
```

Maybe firewalld is using the `REJECT` above, but it looks fine with `icmp-host-prohibited`. However I dont get that answer on a client.

`iptables -vnL`:

```
Chain IN_internal (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_internal_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_internal_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_internal_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: The `iptables` rules are processed in order, and since you seem to have a DROP rule that matches all invalid packets before the REJECT rule, the processing may never reach the REJECT rule. However, `iptables -L` does not always tell the whole story: it omits the fields that would indicate if a particular rule applies to specific interface(s) only. You should probably use `iptables -Lvn` instead, so that the full meaning of each rule can be reviewed.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of that. However if I'm not mistaken this is solely managed by firewalld. Or could I just change the order? Wouldn't that interfere with firewalld?

Comment: The internal chain ends with a REJECT. So that should be fine. Unfortunately I can't test it at the moment. If the the chain reaches a REJECT, it shouldn't matter what follows, right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. You may want to place two REJECTs at the end of the internal chain: first one that matches the TCP protocol only and uses a TCP RST as its reject type (in `iptables` lingo, it's `iptables [...] -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`; I don't remember the `firewalld` equivalent right now), then another REJECT for everything else, using the default ICMP reject response.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! Yes it might be just a TCP related problem. I'll try to add a rich rule or something comparable for TCP and see if that work. If my memory serves me right, pings were actutally rejected, but a http request, for example, appeared to be dropped. So it might just have been the wrong answer (`icmp-host-prohibited` instead of `tcp-reset`). I'll update as soon as I've tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes some operating systems may fail to respond appropriately to `icmp-host-prohibited` messages for TCP connections, as the classic expected way to reject a TCP connection is by a TCP RST packet. (Or maybe some firewalls fail to recognize that ICMP response as related to a TCP connection attempt, and filter it out?)

The default rejection method of `iptables` (and by extension, also `firewalld`) is `icmp-host-prohibited`, which attempts to be a "one-size-fits-all" rejection method applicable equally for all protocols. As a result, you may wish to add a custom rejection rule for TCP packets, using the reject type of `tcp-reset`.

The `firewall-cmd` syntax for the rich rule for TCP rejection would be something like this:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="tcp" reject type="tcp-reset"'
```